# Send userID and access_token facebook from client side to server

Tags: asp.net, facebook-javascript-sdk

I just started to use the facebook login app for my website. After login success, I received the response which contains some info like `userID, access_token, signedRequest, etc`. I need to pass this info to my server side to get user data (email, picture) and add that to my database. If I use ajax call to my server, my server API will be exposed. My question is how can I pass that info to server-side without worrying my server will be exposed?
Note: I'm using ASP.Net.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Access Token only, and use a server side API call (including `appsecret_proof`) to get the User ID. Only store the User ID.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests